# Font equivalent to Arial Unicode MS

Tags: fonts

Is there a free Unicode font equivalent to [Arial Unicode MS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial_Unicode_MS)?

Arial Unicode MS is not free, and I need font to support various languages in my [Flex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flex) application.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [DejaVu](https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/) font, which is an extension of *Bitstream Vera*.

Comment: Aren't there only about 300 characters in the Bitstream Vera font?

Comment: Yes, DejaVu is an extension of Vera because of that reason, sorry my answer should have been more elaborate.

Comment: I think that this URL is broken now, seems to link to a somewhat shady page. I think it should now link to https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/ instead.

Comment: Thank you, I updated the link. Instead of commenting, you may also suggest edits to an answer with such a fix.

Answer (score 5):

You can try [Google Noto Fonts](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) which is a collection of fonts that cover most of the ranges specified in the Unicode standard.

If you are wondering if there is any way to merge all these multiple fonts into single font then the below discussion link will be of interesting to you.

[Single ttf for all languages?](https://github.com/googlei18n/noto-fonts/issues/13)