# Arial Unicode MS font equivalent in Linux

Tags: linux, unicode, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Font equivalent to Arial Unicode MS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370512/font-equivalent-to-arial-unicode-ms)

Hi,

Is there any free unicode font equivalent to Arial Unicode MS in Linux?

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software_Unicode_fonts

Comment: Which particular character ranges do you need? The two in the other question's answer don't seem to be that complete, or certainly not compared to Arial Unicode. [Wikipedia's list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_typefaces) with character / glyph counts

Comment: I need Japanese and Chinese language support in Linux.

Comment: Arial Unicode is a poor choice for CJK (and in general, really).